# RSA-шифрование (длина ключа)

Tags: криптография, rsa, шифрование

Объясните, пожалуйста. Скажем, я зашифровал две буквы RSA шифрованием, и у меня вышли вот такие числа: {836587,763111} (они верные). Так вот, как мне узнать, у меня получилось RSA-16, или RSA-32, или RSA-64?

Comment: Я че-то не совсем понимаю - а что значит RSA-16?

16 - это длина ключа? Ну так значит смотри на длину ключа - сколько бит, столько RSA и будет )

Comment: Ну да, то есть просто нужно перевести в двоичную?

Comment: Да, [вот здесь](http://www.cyberguru.ru/algorithms/cryptography/rsa-page7.html) примерно расписано. Хотя там данные немного устарели, т.к. 768-битные ключи уже вломали, поэтому мозила отказалась даже от 1024-битных ключей. И говорят, в течение 3-4 лет уже и 1024-битные сломают.

Т.е. вам надо просто посмотреть на N (т.е. число, которое вы получили, умножением P на Q) - его длина в битах и есть длина ключа.